# Bootswatch symbol in Chrome tab

Tags: macos, google-chrome, icon, tabs

A strange thing happen to my chrome web browser, and I don't know why, I hope you can help me.

In my chrome tabs the bootswatch symbol appears in the tab icon even when I'm not in the bootswatch website!!

[image]

I have already uninstalled the chrome browser using the AppCleaner.app, and I also checked if I had some weird extension installed.

I really don't know why this happens, it is strange. I am programming in ruby on rails and I have browsed and tried bootswatch, but I don't know why this has affected my browser!

Any help?

**Edit1:**

Even when I search for something the icon is there in the tab

[image]

[image]

**Edit2:**

Even in my tablet I have the icon!

[image]

**Edit3:**

If I delete this file:
`macosxssd/Users/mario/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks`

or this file
`macosxssd/Users/mario/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Favicons`

It disappear in both devices, but It is temporary. The files are generated again.

**Edit4:**

Search for bootswatch in my computer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Clear your cache.  Settings->advanced->clear browsing data.  Make sure you select Clear Cache from 'beginning of time'.  Restart browser.

Also, fyi, the favicon cache file is here, you can may try deleting that and restarting the browser.  The steps above would essentially do the same thing: 
/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Favicons

Comment: The clear cache didn't work, but it worked with the "Also" option that you pointed me.
Thanks a lot @Hefewelzen!

Comment: It was temporary, It is there again, and even in my tablet.

Comment: Does this happen from a different internet connection?

Comment: Yes, both in my home internet connection, and in other different internet connections.

Comment: If you clear the cache as mentioned, then go to a different network, does it come back? I suspect your router or gateway is somehow injecting this information (and possibly other, malicious information).

Comment: Yes exactly Elliott, that's what I was thinking, possible DNS redirect.  He could also manually set his IP address and DNS to root dns or opendns and clearing cache.

Comment: Check your proxy settings - perhaps something has inserted itself there.